# Não imprime os dígitos numéricos

Tags: c, formatação

> ```
> 1 - Crie um programa em linguagem C, que tenha os seguintes itens (0.5 pontos).
> a) Armazenar em uma constante do tipo caractere, o número do seu RA sem o traço.
> b) Criar um vetor do tipo inteiro com o tamanho da *string* armazenada na sua constante.
> c) Alimentar o vetor de forma que cada caractere do seu RA, que está na constante, fique armazenado em uma posição do seu novo vetor. Para isso, utilize um laço de repetição.
> d) Imprimir o vetor preenchido de forma que apareça um número em cada linha. Para isso, utilize um laço de repetição diferente do utilizado na alternativa anterior.
> ```

Meu código é este:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{

     const char *RA = "19480685";
     int vetor[strlen(RA)];

     for (int i = 0; i < strlen(RA); i++) vetor[i]=RA[i];

     for (int i = 0; i < strlen(RA); i++) printf ("%d\n", vetor[i]);



    return 0;
}
```

Porém o resultado do programa sai com esses números aleatórios:

[image: resultado]

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Você está mandando imprimir número (`%d`), e quer imprimir caracteres (`%c`), este é o erro. Além disso eu guardei o tamanho da *string* em uma variável porque a função `strlen()` é extremaente lenta e nem, deveria ser usada, dava neste caso, mas o enunciado pedia para fazer assim. O enunciado é ambíguo em alguns pontos.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main() {
    const char *RA = "19480685";
    int tamanho = strlen(RA);    
    int vetor[tamanho];
    for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) vetor[i] = RA[i];
    for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) printf ("%c\n", vetor[i]);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/JeHxWK). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/GetAlgarism). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/GetAlgarism.c).

Comment: em vez de "for", como eu uso "while" pra imprimir esse vetor?

Comment: Isso não está na pergunta, eu respondi o que perguntou. E não é necessário fazer isto.

Comment: é q na pergunta ta falando que tem q usar 2 laços diferentes, e eu so usei o for por enquanto :/

Comment: Na verdade você usou 3, um invisível e dois visíveis, não sei porque está falando que usou 1.

Comment: dos laços (for, while, do while), desses que estou falando

Comment: Não é isso que está no enunciado, ele só quer dois laços diferentes, não quer que você use um `while`.

Comment: o professor disse que queria usar 2 tipos de laços de repetição diferentes nas alternativas C, D

Comment: Não está no enunciado, você está com problemas de interpretação de texto e de qualquer forma não faz sentido fazer isso.

Comment: Estou com um erro, quando eu executo seu codigo no dev c++ da um erro.  

([Error] 'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 or C11 mode)

([Error] redefinition of 'i')

([Error] 'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 or C11 mode)

Antes tava em C++,  e nao tava acontecendo o erro, e agora ta em C oq ue pode ser?

Comment: Não use o Dev-C++ ele é conhecidamente muito ruim, mas tem que configurar a compilação para C99 ou C11 conforme a mensagem de erro faz, mas esse problema é outra coisa, não faz parte da pergunta que você fez aqui. Cada problema deve ser uma pergunta diferente.